# still getting error: 'implement abstract method 'onFocusChange(View, boolean)' in 'OnFocusChangeListener' even when the method has been implemented

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-view, anonymous-function

I'm trying to implement `OnFocusChangeListener` on an `EditText`. The problem is I'm getting this error

> Class 'FacilityScreen' must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract method 'onFocusChange(View, boolean)' in
>   'OnFocusChangeListener'

even though the method `onFocusChange` has been implemented in `OnFocusChangeListener`.

Here is my code

```
 public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,View.OnFocusChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facilty_screen);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
                if(hasfocus){
                     //do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  **`@Override`**   **`public void onFocusChange()`** method inside your activity

Than use like this **`editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this)`**

> **Check this example**

```
public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnFocusChangeListener{

    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facilty_screen);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if(view==editText){
            // perfom your action here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @nilesh-rathod. Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555339/still-getting-error-implement-abstract-method-onfocuschangeview-boolean-i

Answer (score 1):

**Version 1 - handle listener on class level**

If you want the class to handle the listener then you have to tell the view so:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

Then you have to implement `onFocusChange` on the class level. *Android Studio* should help you to do this with a few clicks. The outcome should be something like:

```
 public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        //your other methods

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

**Version 2 - handle listener inline as anonymous class**

You are actually so far using an anonymous class to handle the listener inline. If you want to listen there and not on class level, then simply remove the `OnFocusChangeListener` from the class level. I.e. remove `implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,View.OnFocusChangeListener` and leave the rest as it is.

Comment: thanks @michael-troger. Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555339/still-getting-error-implement-abstract-method-onfocuschangeview-boolean-i

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to implement it in Activity, replace

```
 public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,View.OnFocusChangeListener
```

to

```
 public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity
```

Alternatively, you could override the onFocusChange method in Activity itself and then set it in editText, like this:

```
public class FacilityScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,View.OnFocusChangeListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facilty_screen);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_location);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class implements an interface. That means that class (in your example: Activity), must Override all non-abstract methods in class.
Here, you've mixed two approaches. If you implement an interface in your class declaration, you don't need to create new instance of inner class like

```
 new OnFocusChangeListener() {
//override a method
}
```

It's OK, to leave your code as it is, just remove. In this case, you use inner class approach. Creating anonymous instance and overriding a non-abstract method.

```
implements View.OnFocusChangeListener
```